# I want to constructively link helpful answers from other sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, third-party

Sometimes I'll follow a link from a StackExchange answer to an external website, and that website will help me find the answer.  Or sometimes I can't find the actual question (& answer) on StackExchange but I will find the exact thing I'm looking for somewhere else.

I would love to see a feature allowing people to tag webpages as answers (a la trackbacks in blogs) rather than just posting "See this page, it might help".  Likewise, I want to be able to "upvote" a helpful blog post that answered my question, and have that "upvote" be visible/searchable on StackExchange.

Those features would totally make my day.

**Edited** for clarity, since it seems I didn't appropriately state my use cases in the original post:

- Step 1) A question is asked on SE
- Step 2) The answer exists on
  another website out there, like a nettuts site or blog
- Step 3) I have
  some mechanism for attaching a link to that site as an answer to the
  question on SE
- Step 4) SE goes out and grabs the content of the post
  and preserves it as an answer, along with the ability to up/downvote

This allows me to provide helpful information that answers a question, without just posting an answer that says "maybe this site will help" with a link, and it preserves the content of linked sites so that if they go down or the link otherwise breaks the "answer" is still here on SE.

Another potential workflow:

- Step 1) I have a question and I don't find that question on SE (and by extension, I don't find the answer)
- Step 2) I go to Google again, and find a 3rd party site that *does* answer my question
- Step 3) I tell SE about that website, both as a question and an answer
- Step 4) SE is able to preserve the content of that site and allow it to show up on SE, get tagged, upvotes/downvotes, etc

This allows me to easily flag relevant information.  The current alternate workflow would be for me to specifically some back to SE, post the question myself, then copy-and-paste the answer from the 3rd party website, and answer the question myself.  Very backwards.

In both cases, the person linking to the site *currently* gets credit for the helpful answer, but in reality the other site is the helpful one.

Comment: They're called comments. And what do you know, you can upvote them.

Comment: Meh, I want to down-vote and vote-to-close lots of external web-sites.  Upvoting, is less interesting.

Comment: @animuson methinks you miss the point.  The answer doesn't exist on SE, but it does exist elsewhere.  So why not be able to link the answer in a constructive way that preserves the answer?

Answer (score 12):

I don't like the idea of just links, as we all know links can and do break over time.  We should stick with linking to a site in an answer with a summary of or passage from the relevant verbiage in the page linked.  If it's helpful then the answer can be upvoted.

Comment: That was kind of the idea -- a la trackbacks.  You flag a webpage as being relevant to a question, SE/SO goes out and grabs a snippet of that blog and posts it (and therefore preserves it).

Comment: The logic to grab the relevant text from the page is a bit over the top.  It's much better for humans to do this.